# Prioritize Row within View based on Taxonomy Term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am generating rows through a view and have specific requirement for listing on my page.

What I want is if there is one specific term value of my Filter Taxonomy, the row should show itself first.

For each result of this view, I have a term value of one taxonomy (Role).

Possible term values for this Taxonomy (Role) are:-

- Leader
- Manager
- Editor
- User

Now what I want is, that which ever row's Taxonomy value is `Leader`, the row should be shown first and then the `Manager`, then the `Editor` and at the end, of `User`.

Any help how I could achieve this in Views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your view, for **Sort Criteria** remove whatever you're current using (post date is usually the default) and add Taxonomy term: Weight

Then go to admin/structure/taxonomy go to list terms and click on show row weight link (far right) and give them different weight numbers, or use the four arrows icon to drag them and arrearage them in the order you want them to show in.

Comment: Hi, I was hoping not to sort, but to show all the results with specific term first. So first example, I want to show all rows with taxonomy term of Leaders first.

Comment: Sorting is what you want. You could as well group the results by terms, but this is also "sorting".

Comment: You should try my answer, the sort will rearrange them like you want them.